# calling fclose on a private variable with reflection

Tags: php, reflection, private-members

Private variables can be set thusly:

```
function setVar($obj, $var, $val)
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($obj));
    $prop = $reflection->getProperty($var);
    $prop->setAccessible(true);
    return $prop->setValue($obj, $val);
}
```

But that's not that helpful when you're dealing with a function like `fclose()`.

Superficially it seems like something like this could work:

Private varaibles can be accessed thusly:

```
function &getVar($obj, $var)
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($obj));
    $prop = $reflection->getProperty($var);
    $prop->setAccessible(true);
    return $prop->getValue($obj);
}

fclose(&$getVar($obj, 'fsock'));
```

But in my testing it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `&`, it works just fine.

```
function getVar($obj, $var){
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($obj));
    $prop = $reflection->getProperty($var);
    $prop->setAccessible(true);
    return $prop->getValue($obj);
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
class Foo{
    private $handle;
}
$foo = new Foo;

$handle = fopen(__FILE__,'rb');
if($handle){
    echo "file opened\n";
    setVar($foo, 'handle', $handle);
    if(fclose(getVar($foo, 'handle'))) echo "file closed\n";
}
```

Output:

```
file opened
file closed
```